# Generation of centroids outside polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, centroids

I have a polygons layer and creating a centroid layer of it, some of them are generated outside my polygon, what cause a selection problem after.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: If we had FAQ then centroids falling outside their polygons would certainly be there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no problem, a centroid doesn't need to be within the polygon. If you need a point that must be inside the polygon then you should use either `pointOnSurface` or `poleOfInacessability` which do always fall inside the polygon.